# How to override autocomplete_fields style in Django 2.0?

Tags: django, django-forms

I use *autocomplete_fields* to search and select my many to many items in admin view.
Using this widget I am unable to override size of box. Instead with other simple fields (textbox, textarea, etc) I can specify style in my forms.py page in this way:

**forms.py**

```
class ModelBAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'm2m_fields']

        widgets = { 
            "name": forms.TextInput(attrs={'min-width': '400px'}),
            "description": forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': '20'}),
            "m2m_fields": forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'min-width': '400px'})
        }
```

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(ModelB)
class ModelBAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'description')
    search_fields = ('name', 'description')

    date_hierarchy = 'created_at'

    autocomplete_fields = ('m2m_fields',)
    form = forms.ModelBAdminForm
```

Analyzing the html I saw the combobox uses a "select2" class.
How can I increase min-width of the MultiSelect box?

Comment: Any solution for this?